# When can we surely tell about independence of two continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-probability

Assume $X$ and $Y$ are two continuous random variables.
Assuming the given conditions to be true does any of them concretely tell us that X and Y are independent.
$$1.\ P(X > a | Y > a) = P(X > a)\ \forall\ a\ \in\ \mathbb{R}$$

$$2.\ P(X > a| Y < b) = P(X > a)\ \forall\ a,\ b\ \in\ \mathbb{R}\\$$

Why would $(2)$ always imply random variables $X$ and $Y$ to be independent but not $(1)$?

Please help me understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say we had some random variables $X$ and $Y$ such that $P(X > a \cap Y > b) = \frac{a}{b}P(X > a)P(Y > b)$ for $b > a > 0$, else $P(X > a)P(Y > b).$

Clearly, letting $a = b$ would satisfy the first criterion:

$$P(X > a | Y > a) = \frac{P(X > a \cap Y > a)}{P(Y > a)} = \frac{\frac{a}{a}P(X>a)P(Y>a)}{P(Y>a)} = P(X>a)$$

However, for $a = 2, b = 1$ we have $P(X > a | Y > b) = \frac{1}{2}P(X > a) \neq P(X > a),$ so the variables are not independent.

Now, suppose we have our second criterion, $P(X > a|Y < b) = P(X > a).$

Let's rewrite the events $X > a$ and $Y < b$ as $A$ and $B$ for simplicity.

By Bayes' rule:

$$P(A|\bar{B}) = \frac{P(\bar{B}|A)P(A)}{P(\bar{B})} = (1 - P(B|A))\frac{P(A)}{1 - P(B)}$$
$$ = \frac{P(A) - P(A|B)P(B)}{P(A)}\cdot \frac{P(A)}{1 - P(B)} = \frac{P(A)-P(A|B)P(B)}{1-P(B)}$$

Now, notice that from our second criterion we have $P(A|B) = P(A).$ So:

$$\frac{P(A)-P(A|B)P(B)}{1-P(B)} = P(A)\frac{1 - P(B)}{1 - P(B)} = P(A)$$

Which is to say that $P(X>a|Y>b)=P(X>a).$

Comment: My question was for $P(X > a \cap Y < b)$ but you have answered it according to $P(X > a \cap Y > b)$.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it may have been a typo. I will edit to correct this

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Since I'm a new member, I'm unable to upvote your answer. I request you to upvote the question so that I get the privilege to upvote.

Comment: do random variables with $P(X > a \cap Y > b) = \frac{a}{b}P(X > a)P(Y > b)$ actually exist? (is the RHS even in $[0,1]$?)

Comment: I'll add the clarification that $b > a$ so that it's guaranteed that the probability is less than $1,$ but ultimately the point is it shows a more general flaw with the condition: replace $\frac{a}{b}$ with any function $f(a,b)$ such that $f(a,a) = 1.$

Comment: Okay, but it's still IMHO not clear whether there exist random variables $X$, $Y$ that satisfy this condition... Could you give a concrete counterexample?

Comment: I'm still having doubt that assuming $P(X > a | Y < b) = P(X > a)\ \forall\ a,\ b\ \in\ \mathbb{R}$ condition to be true does it prove X and Y to be independent always?

Comment: @hgmath Admittedly I don't have the background in probability theory required for me to name such an example, that may have to be a job for someone else. Sorry

Comment: @TuhinDutta Do you agree that the steps I show prove that $P(X>a|Y < b) = P(X>a)$ implies that $P(X>a|Y>b) = P(X>a)$ for any given real $a,b$? If so then it should be clear that we can conclude that the implication holds for all real $a,b.$

Comment: @StephenDonovan Yes, I do agree. I think now I have got the intuition clear. Thanks.